# XSLT of tasks webpart in 2013 / 2010

Tags: 2010, 2013, xslt

I'm curious and maybe someone could help me to get the XSLT of the My Tasks webpart in SharePoint 2010 and 2013, i tried to find it out, but i cannot find it anywhere.

SP 2013 I don't have, but if someone could give me link or post it here, i would apprecieate ...

And for SP 2010 if anyone could tell me how to find it out?

Another question if i want to inherit from My Tasks webpart, which class should I inherit from then? I cant find this either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The OWA My Tasks web part is not an XSLT-based web part, thus there is no answer to that part of your question.

The web part definition of this web part is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
         <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
         <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWATasksPart</TypeName>
         <Title>My Tasks</Title>
         <Description>Displays your tasks using Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 or later.</Description>
         <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/wp_pers.gif</PartImageLarge>
    </WebPart>
```

If you wanted to create a custom web part with this web part as your base, you can use the Type Name and assembly referenced in the XML. You may also want to take a peak at that code using .NET Reflector or other reflection tool so you can understand how the web part is structured before getting too deep into it.

Comment: Do you know any xslt that could transfrom the results into something like the my tasks webpart?